# PHP. Possible to use variable for object?

Tags: php, variables, object

-EDIT- Yes this actually does work. I see that now...

Is it possible to use a variable to determine a property?

I have 2 classes that are called as part of my controller

```
$this->document->setPageNum
```

and

```
$this->document2->setPageNum
```

I would like to use something like

```
if (is_array($pagenum)) {
    $doc = 'document';
} else {
    $doc = 'document2';
}

$this->$doc->setPageNum = $pagenum;
```

Is that possible to do?

Comment: wouldn't it be a fun experience to just try it out? o.o

Comment: ah. damn.. I did try and didn't work. Didn't bother to realize I had typo. It does work exactly like I hoped. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, [it does work](http://www.ideone.com/0uia5). ;-)

Answer (score 3):

why not save yourself the trouble of confusing code and just set the variable equal to the actual object you want, like so:

```
if (is_array($pagenum)) {
    $doc = $this->document;
} else {
    $doc = $this->document2;
}

$doc->setPageNum = $pagenum;
```